# how to update URl when selecting a value from dynamic picklist in vf page?

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

I have an issue with changing url when i am selecting a value from my picklist.

```
<apex:actionFunction name="updateCategory" action="{!updateCategory}" rerender="posts" status="updateStatus">
    <apex:param name="param" assignTo="{!selectedCategory}" value="{!discussionPageNum}"  />
</apex:actionFunction>

<div class="ibtFilterStatus">
    <apex:actionStatus startText="Updating..." id="updateStatus" startStyle="padding-right: 10px;"/>
    <span class="select" id="select7">All Categories</span> 
    <apex:selectList id="ideacategories" value="{!selectedCategory}" size="1" onchange="hideSubscribeButton();  updateCategory(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value); doSearch('select7', this, 'ideaCategories')">
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!categories}" />
    </apex:selectList>&nbsp;
</div>

<div style="float: right" id="test">
    <apex:outputLink style="margin-right:5px;font-size: 13px;{!IF(hasDiscussionNextPage,'','display:none;')}" value="?discussionPg={!discussionPageNum + 1}&ideaCategory={!selectedCategory}">Previous Discussion</apex:outputLink>
</div>
```

How can I rerender my div with id="test" when i am selecting a category?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a solution for this..

I just do redirection in my action function method named update category. and its working well..

thanks laceySnr for all your replies...

Comment: Ah, I thought you mean the URL in your link wasn't changing, didn't realise you wanted to redirect the browser.

Comment: yes i want to change my url in my link to change but that thing can only be done when your page is reloaded .. that's why i use redirection.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can only rerender page elements that have been generated though a VF tag (I may be wrong here, I've not tried it!

replace the div with an outputPanel (it'll generate the same markup):

```
<apex:outputPanel styleClass="output" id="test">
    <apex:outputLink ...
</apex:outputPanel>
```

You'll notice I've used a CSS class rather than inline styling, it's best practice to do this and then put the styling in a `<style>` block in your header.

After changing to the output panel, then specify it for rerender in the `updateCategory` action function:

```
rerender="posts, test" **
```

Of course, if, as I suspect, doSearch is also an action function, I'd suggest doing the rerender from that one since that is the last function to execute.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your reply... but its not working.. its not updating my url.. do u have any other options...

Comment: Does the re-render work? If you put {!selectedCategory} just visible on the page inside that panel does it's value change?

Comment: ya.. ol other functionality is doing well.